# Unresolved reference: androidContext

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I wanted to add context to the parameters of

> Room.database Builder(context: Context, klass: Class, name:
> String?)

I want to add `androidContext()` from Kotlin. But it shows that androidContext() was not found

```
val dataBaseModule = module {
    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(androidContext())
    }
}
```

[image]

Here's my build.gradle(:data)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(path: ':domain')

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    //Networking
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.2"

    //Database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0"

    //DI
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.0.1"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:2.0.1"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:2.0.1"
}
```

I tried adding different dependencies, but couldn't find clear solutions that would help me

Comment: You can try using `androidApplication` instead of `androidContext()`

Comment: and how do I get it?